# MySQL select from two table based on multiple conditions in same table

Tags: mysql, database, join

I'm trying to build a filter to quickly find the right product based on some specifications. But I can't get the MySQL to work. Been gooogling for a while now but can't find a similar question. I hope you can help me.

```
This is the products table
--------------------
|  id  |  name     |
--------------------
|   1  | Product 1 |
|   2  | Product 2 |
|   3  | Product 3 |
--------------------

This is the relation table for the specifications
--------------------------------
|  id  |  specs_id  |  prod_id  |
--------------------------------
|   1  |     1      |     1     |
|   2  |     5      |     1     |
|   3  |     6      |     2     |
|   4  |     9      |     3     |
|   5  |     11     |     2     |
---------------------------------
```

This is the MySQL how I want it to work.

```
$sql = "SELECT p.id, p.name                 
        FROM products p
        JOIN specs s ON p.id = s.prod_id
        WHERE s.specs_id = 1
        AND s.specs_id = 5
        AND s.specs_id = 7
        GROUP BY p.id";
```

This example will give no result

```
$sql = "SELECT p.id, p.name
        FROM products p
        JOIN specs s ON p.id = s.prod_id
        WHERE s.specs_id = 1
        AND s.specs_id = 5
        GROUP BY p.id";
```

This will return product with ID 1

Comment: `s.item_id` There is no `item_id` in the spec table, not the one you show us anyway

Comment: My guess would be you mean `s.prod_id`

Comment: My bad. It's supposed to be prod_id. I have changed it now.

Answer (score 2):

Item_id does not exist in your table. You also used **AND** insted of **OR**, thus no entry could match. None can have the specs_id 2,5, and 7 at the same time.

```
SELECT p.id, p.name                 
FROM products p
JOIN specs s
ON p.id = s.prod_id
WHERE s.specs_id = 5
OR s.specs_id = 2
OR s.specs_id = 7
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Comment: But if OR is used it will not be an exact match or am I thinking wrong. Let's say specs_id 1,5, and 6 is used it will return product 1 and 2. I want it to be no match then.

Comment: you are right OR will either of result not inclusive of 1,5,7.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `OR` or `IN` is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.name
FROM products p
  JOIN specs s ON p.id = s.prod_id
WHERE s.specs_id IN (1,5);
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.name
FROM products p
  JOIN specs s ON p.id = s.prod_id
WHERE s.specs_id=1 OR s.specs_id=5;
```

Also, use `DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY` if you do not have aggregate functions.

Comment: this will also give result. Upvoting

Comment: I tried it but it will not give an exact match. It will also return product 1 and 2 if you select 1,5, 6

Comment: Maybe you could add expected result to the question with different parameters. With `specs_id`'s 1,5,6, you should get products 1 and 2 unless you want something different.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like first filter `specs` table with required `specs_id` and then make join that result with `products` table.

```sql
select p.id, p.name from 
(select * from products p ) p 
join (select * from specs where specs_id in (1,5,7)) s
on p.id = s.prod_id
group by p.id
```

Comment: yes, I have tried it and the result is the same as the answers above. There is no exact match. I don't know if i'm totally wrong about how to do this. I want to narrow down the results when more specification is selected instead of getting more results. I get the impression that this would be easy to fix but it doesn't seems like that. Thanks for your help.